# PostgreSQL table size larger than raw data text files

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table in my PostgreSQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE values
(
    dt        timestamp,
    series_id integer,
    value     real
);
CREATE INDEX idx_values_date ON public."values" USING btree (dt);
ALTER TABLE ONLY public."values" ADD CONSTRAINT values_series_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (series_id) REFERENCES public.series(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

I'm parsing some CSV files and extracting floats which I add to this table together with a timestamp and series_id which is a foreign key to another table.

The directory containing my raw data files amounts to about 28MB on my drive.
After feeding the data into my table I do a

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_total_relation_size('values') );
```

And find that the table now has ~871503 rows and is now 98MB in size. Is this normal? I was expecting my table to be way less in 
size than actual text files containing raw data.
I'd like to mention that the PostgreSQL instance also has PostGIS installed but I'm not using it
in this particular schema. Furthermore, I'm running PostgreSQL from a docker container.

Later edit ...

After doing some more research and running the following query:

```
SELECT *, pg_size_pretty(total_bytes) AS total
    , pg_size_pretty(index_bytes) AS INDEX
    , pg_size_pretty(toast_bytes) AS toast
    , pg_size_pretty(table_bytes) AS TABLE
  FROM (
  SELECT *, total_bytes-index_bytes-COALESCE(toast_bytes,0) AS table_bytes FROM (
      SELECT c.oid,nspname AS table_schema, relname AS TABLE_NAME
              , c.reltuples AS row_estimate
              , pg_total_relation_size(c.oid) AS total_bytes
              , pg_indexes_size(c.oid) AS index_bytes
              , pg_total_relation_size(reltoastrelid) AS toast_bytes
          FROM pg_class c
          LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
          WHERE relkind = 'r'
  ) a
) a WHERE a.table_name = 'values';
```

I came up with the following results:

```
Index: 61MB
Table: 38MB
```

Can I somehow optimize the index? Maybe it's using some defaults that make it take up so much space?

Comment: Yes, that's to be  expected. There is an overhead in storing data in a relational database.

Comment: I've added more information in the meantime. Is it normal for the index to take up close to twice the space taken by the actual data?

Comment: Your create table doesn't show any indexes.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Isn't that overhead a bit excessive, considering that string `2019-12-10 13:11:23,4636325,525.326236` takes 38 bytes, but in PostgreSQL respective columns with that DDL would be (in bytes) 8, 4, 4?

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński I'd say 38MB vs. 28MB is not too far apart. There is an overhead of 23byte per row plus alignment considerations. As there is no information about the index, it's hard to judge that

Comment: Added index and constraint definitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I populate a table with your structure with that number of rows, I get:

```
table: 37 MB
index: 24 MB
```

So either your index is bloated (you can drop and recreate it, or use REINDEX) or you have more indexes than you are admitting to.

But perhaps the better answer is "Yes, relational databases have a lot of overhead, get used to it."  If you try to investigate every difference between a database and a flat file, you will drive yourself crazy and accomplish very little from it.

Comment: REINDEX sometimes cuts index size in half after many inserts using COPY